# Country autosuggest is working but failsed in webproxy?

Tags: json, codeigniter, jsonp, webproxy

I am building a codeigniter site which is almost done. In my site country autosuggest is working fine. But when I am trying to acces the site with webproxy hidedoor.com, country auto suggest is not working. I really dont know whow to tackle it. I had tried unsuccesssful attempt of jsonp as well. So can you guy's help me? 
my json handling code is,

```
$(function() {
$("#ville").autocomplete({
source: function(request, response) {

                $.ajax({ url: "<?php echo base_url().'autocomplete/suggestcity'; ?>",
                data: { term: $("#ville").val()},
                 crossDomain: true,
                dataType: "json",
                //jsonp: 'callback',
                //dataType: "html",
                type: "POST",

                success: function(data){

                    var citydetails = new Array();
                    for(i=0; i<data.lang.length; i++)
                    {
                        citydetails[i]=data.lang[i]+', '+data.countryname[i];

                    }
                    response(citydetails);

                    $(".ui-menu-item a").click(function(){
                        set_value($(this).html());

                        for(i=0; i<=citydetails.length; i++)
                        {
                            if(citydetails[i] == $(this).html()){
                                $("#co_num").val(data.co_num[i]);
                                $("#geoname_id").val(data.geoname_id[i]);
                            }
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
        });
    });
```

Comment: what's the response, have you tried seeing the response using "alert(data)"?

Comment: Thank's for replying Naveed. In firebug it showing 200 ok but in response tab everythingis blank.

Comment: that means your web service is not working correctly. i dont know about the proxy thing you're using, but i think it should not affect the behavious. try accessing the url in a different tab.
For example, localhost/autocomplete/suggestcity in your browser